# php 5.6 curl TLS 1.2 update

Tags: php, curl, php-5.6, php-curl

Want to Update TLS version 1.2 with PHP 5.6 having Problem after code change in Curl request

```
function callNewAPI($apiURL, $requestParamList) {
    $jsonResponse = "";
    $responseParamList = array();
    $JsonData =json_encode($requestParamList);
    $postData = 'JsonData='.urlencode($JsonData);
    $ch = curl_init($apiURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    **curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);**
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                         
    'Content-Type: application/json', 
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postData))                                                                       
    );  
    $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);   
    $responseParamList = json_decode($jsonResponse,true);
    return $responseParamList;
}
```

The response is not getting success .is there anything need to configure
OpenSSL/1.0.1p
PHP 5.6

Comment: When you say "the response is not getting success", you should post the phenomenon which makes you know that "the response is not getting success", too.

Comment: What does phpinfo() show for curl extension?

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the verbose log. add error detection to curl_exec, check if curl_errno() returns int(0), does it?